# C++ Error - no matching function for call

Tags: c++

I am having some problems trying to compile my code because of an error.

It is in function *mergeSort* , line: `merge(a, from, mid, to);` :

> Invalid arguments ' Candidates are:
>      2 merge(#0, #0, #1, #1, #2, #3)
>      2 merge(#0, #0, #1, #1, #2) ' no matching function for call to merge(std::vector >&, int&, int&, int&)

```cpp
    void mergeSort(vector<string> &a, int from, int to)
    {
        if (from == to)
        {
            return;
        }
        int mid = (from + to) / 2;

        mergeSort(a, from, mid);
        mergeSort(a, mid + 1, to);
        merge(a, from, mid, to);

    } // end mergeSort

     void merge(vector<string> &a, int from, int mid, int to)
    {
        int n = to - from + 1; 
        vector<string> b(n); 
        int i1 = from;
        int i2 = mid + 1; 
        int j = 0; 

        while (i1 <= mid && i2 <= to)
        {
            if (a[i1].compare(a[i2]) < 0)
            {
                b[j] = a[i1];
                i1++;
            }
            else
            {
                b[j] = a[i2];
                i2++;
            }
            j++;
        }

        while (i1 <= mid)
        {
            b[j] = a[i1];
            i1++;
            j++;
        }

        while (i2 <= to)
        {
            b[j] = a[i2];
            i2++;
            j++;
        }

        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            a[from + j] = b[j];
        }
    } 

     int main() {
        vector<string> v = {"Apple", "Fruit", "Banana", "apple", "4apples", "applesauce", "3bananas", "\"apple\""}

        //  Print original vector
                cout << "******Original*******"<< endl;
                for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
                {

                  cout << v[i] << endl;
                }

               mergeSort(v, 0, v.size() - 1);

                cout << "******MERGE SORTED*******"<< endl;
                for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
                {

                      cout << v[i] << endl;
                }

        }
```

Comment: Presumably you are erroneously using `using namespace std`, which is causing the (vagueish) compiler errors. Had you not done this, you would've had a more reasonable error

Comment: Very relevant/duplicate: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 4):

The standard C++ library has its own [`std::merge()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) functions. Those are the candidates you see described in the compiler error as not matching. It does not appear the compiler is even considering your `merge()` function. This implies that you have not declared your function before trying to use it, and that you have a `using namespace std` statement in your code.

You need to declare your function. And you need to either get rid of the `using` statement or else declare your function in its own namespace, and then have `mergeSort()` be explicit about which namespace to pull `merge()` from.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the functions before calling them. Add the following line (declaration of `merge` function), before your `mergeSort` function's definition.

```
void merge(vector<string> &a, int from, int mid, int to);
```

Read about declarations and definitions in C++:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-definition-and-declaration/

[What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

Comment: Alternatively, OP can move the definition of `merge` above the `mergeSort`.